# Flutter: How can I create two column layout with a different sized scrollable ListView in each

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a two column layout in Flutter which has a ListView on the left and three containers in a column on the right. The problem I have is that the containers on the right need to be able to expand as the data changes, which eventually causes a RenderFlex overflow.

With the SingleChildScrollView, the column scroll OK, but once it goes over the viewport constraints, I get the error. I have set the height of the row using a MediaQuery, but this does not seem to have an effect.
The sample code below simulates the situation... Click the add button in the AppBar to increase the size of the text in the containers.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  List<String> _students = ['Gianluca','Lindsay','Leah','U','Marco','Liam','Harrison','Charise','Ting Wei','Ryan','Deena','Xiao Yuan','Benjamin','Calvin','Claudia','Kok Hao','Michalina','Ruby','Rachel','Nadir','Dan','Raaid','Nadia','Matilda','Lloyd','Arielle','Jun','Desmond','Miah','Aiden','Kira','Nathan','Thung Thung','Miki','Yongyou','Brogan','Zai Chern','Gondini','Ella','Germaine'];
  String textData = "";
  int current = 0;
  bool init = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    addName();
    super.initState();
  }

  addName(){
    if(init){
      for(int i=0; i<_students.length;i++){
        textData+= _students[i]+ "   ";
      }
    } else {
      textData += _students[current] + "   ";
      if (current > _students.length) {
        current = 0;
      } else {
        current++;
      }
    }
    setState(() {
    });
    print(textData);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: (){
              addName();
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _students.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return new Text(_students[index]);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text(textData),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: Text(textData),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Text(textData),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify using `ListViews` for both `Columns`:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scan with',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Test(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  List<String> _students = [
    'Gianluca',
    'Lindsay',
    'Leah',
    'U',
    'Marco',
    'Liam',
    'Harrison',
    'Charise',
    'Ting Wei',
    'Ryan',
    'Deena',
    'Xiao Yuan',
    'Benjamin',
    'Calvin',
    'Claudia',
    'Kok Hao',
    'Michalina',
    'Ruby',
    'Rachel',
    'Nadir',
    'Dan',
    'Raaid',
    'Nadia',
    'Matilda',
    'Lloyd',
    'Arielle',
    'Jun',
    'Desmond',
    'Miah',
    'Aiden',
    'Kira',
    'Nathan',
    'Thung Thung',
    'Miki',
    'Yongyou',
    'Brogan',
    'Zai Chern',
    'Gondini',
    'Ella',
    'Germaine'
  ];
  String textData = "";
  int current = 0;
  bool init = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    addName();
    super.initState();
  }

  addName() {
    if (init) {
      for (int i = 0; i < _students.length; i++) {
        textData += _students[i] + "   ";
      }
    } else {
      textData += _students[current] + "   ";
      if (current > _students.length) {
        current = 0;
      } else {
        current++;
      }
    }
    setState(() {});
    print(textData);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              addName();
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _students.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return new Text(_students[index]);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text(textData),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Text(textData),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text(textData),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set ListView in Expanded widget with flex attribute, you can set ratio width of 2 List base on **flex** attribute, the default flex of Expanded is 1, ex: if you want List 2 twice as wide List 1 you set flex = 2.

```
Row(
children:[
Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text('List 1'),),
Expanded(flex: 2, child: Text('List 2'),),
]
),
```

Comment: `flex: 1` is Expanded Widget's default: `Expanded({Key key, int flex: 1, @required Widget child})`